# Event Calendar in JS, CSS, and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, css, dom

I repeated a lot of code here and I'm trying to use more ES6 but I'm not sure where I should have used it in my code. I'd appreciate any input on where I could improve.

[GitHub](https://github.com/aioy/calendar/tree/e3245533f938a4a2e64ab66d11ecb949d1c96a20)

```js
"use strict";
//Calendar

let today = new Date();
let currentMonth = today.getMonth();
let currentYear = today.getFullYear();

let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

 //JSON event data
 let eventData = {
    "events": [
        {
            "description": 'es',
            "year": '2018',
            "month": 'Nov',
            "day": '28'
        }
    ]
 };

let headerMonths = document.getElementsByClassName('month')[0];
let headerYears = document.getElementsByClassName('year')[0];
let next = document.getElementById('next');
let prev = document.getElementById('prev');
let selectYear = document.getElementById('year');
let selectMonth = document.getElementById('month');

selectYear.value=currentYear;
selectMonth.value=currentMonth;

next.addEventListener('click', nextMonth);
prev.addEventListener('click', previousMonth);
selectYear.addEventListener('input', (event)=> {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        jump();
    }
})
selectMonth.addEventListener('change', jump);

showCalendar(currentMonth,currentYear);
showEvents();

function showCalendar(month, year) { 

    let firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();

    let tbl = document.getElementsByClassName("calendar-days")[0]; // body of the calendar

    // clearing all previous cells
    tbl.innerHTML = "";

    // filing data about month and in the page via DOM.
    headerMonths.innerHTML = months[month];
    headerYears.innerHTML = year;

    // creating all cells
    let date = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        // creates a table row
        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        //creating individual cells, filing them up with data.
        for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let cellText = document.createTextNode("");
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            else if (date > daysInMonth(month, year)) {
                break;
            }

            else {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
                if (date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()) {
                    cell.classList.add("active"); // color today's date
                } 
                cell.classList.add('day');
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
                date++;
            }


        }

        tbl.appendChild(row); // appending each row into calendar body.
    }
}

function nextMonth() {
    currentYear = (currentMonth === 11) ? currentYear + 1 : currentYear;
    currentMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    showEvents();
}

function previousMonth() {
    currentYear = (currentMonth === 0) ? currentYear - 1 : currentYear;
    currentMonth = (currentMonth === 0) ? 11 : currentMonth - 1;
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    showEvents();
}

function jump() {
    currentYear = parseInt(selectYear.value);
    currentMonth = parseInt(selectMonth.value);
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    showEvents();
}


function daysInMonth (month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
}


// Events

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript Event Delegation for new elements
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(!e.target.classList.contains('active') && e.target.classList.contains('day')){
        if(document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0] === undefined){
            e.target.classList.add('active');
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].classList.remove('active');
        if(document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0] === undefined){
            e.target.classList.add('active');
        }
        e.target.classList.add('active');
    } else if(e.target.classList.contains('active')===null && e.target.classList.contains('day')){
        e.target.classList.add('active');
    }
 });

//handles new Event form
 let newEvent = {
    // day: parseInt(event.innerHTML),
    desc: document.querySelector('#new-event-desc'),
    month: headerMonths,
    year: headerYears,
    active: document.getElementsByClassName('active'),
    submit: ()=>{
        if(newEvent.desc.value.length===0) {
            newEvent.desc.classList.add('error');
            newEvent.desc.style.border='4px solid red';
        } else {
            newEventJson(newEvent.desc.value, newEvent.month.innerHTML, newEvent.year.innerHTML, newEvent.active[0].innerHTML);
            hideShowEventsDiv();
            showEventText(newEvent.desc.value);
            newEvent.desc.classList.remove('error');
            newEvent.desc.style.border='none';
            newEvent.clear();
        }
    },
    clear: ()=>{
        newEvent.desc.value='';
    }
 };

 const hideShowEventsDiv = ()=> {
     let eventsDiv = document.querySelector('.events');
     let newEventForm = document.querySelector('.new-event-form');
     let saveEventButton = document.querySelector('.submit-event');
     let showEventForm = document.querySelector('.show-event-form');

     if(eventsDiv.classList.contains('hidden')){
         //show Events
        newEventForm.classList.add('hidden');
        newEventForm.classList.remove('visible');
        eventsDiv.classList.remove('hidden');
        eventsDiv.classList.add('visible');
        showEvents();
        //change rotate class for Event listener
        saveEventButton.classList.remove('rotate');
        showEventForm.classList.add('rotate');
     } else {
         //show new Event Form
        eventsDiv.classList.remove('visible');
        eventsDiv.classList.add('hidden');
        newEventForm.classList.remove('hidden');
        newEventForm.classList.add('visible');
        showEventForm.classList.remove('rotate');
        saveEventButton.classList.add('rotate');
     }   
 }

 //Submit form and show event or new event form
 document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.target.classList.contains('rotate') && e.target.classList.contains('submit-event')){
        newEvent.submit();
    } else if(e.target.classList.contains('rotate')) {
        hideShowEventsDiv();
    }
 });

//color the events on the calendar
function showEvents () {
    let days = document.getElementsByClassName('day');
    let events = [];
    [...eventData['events']].forEach((event)=>{
        [...days].forEach((day)=>{
            if(event['day']===day.innerHTML && event['month']===headerMonths.innerHTML && event['year']===headerYears.innerHTML){
                day.classList.add('active-event');
                events.push(event)
            } 
        });
    });
    return events;
}

//clears previous event Text
function clearEventText() {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('event-desc')){
        [...document.getElementsByClassName('event-desc')].forEach((event)=>{
            event.outerHTML='';
        });
    }
}

//shows eventText
function showEventText(desc) {

    let noEvents = document.getElementsByClassName('no-Events')[0];
    let eventsDescContainer = document.querySelector('.events');

        //span element to put Event text into
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        let EventText = document.createTextNode(desc);;

        //delete button for span
        const remove = document.createElement('div');
        let x = document.createTextNode('x');
        remove.appendChild(x);
        remove.classList.add('remove');

        //clear previous events message
        noEvents.classList.remove('show');
        noEvents.style.display='none';

        //append to container
        span.appendChild(EventText)
        span.appendChild(remove);
        span.classList.add('event-desc', 'event-message');
        eventsDescContainer.appendChild(span);
}

//compares eventData array values to date of day clicked on 
const checkEvents = (obj, date)=>{
    let isInArray = eventData['events'].find(event => event[obj]===date)
    return isInArray;
}

// //handler to show text from eventData array
document.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    let noEvents = document.getElementsByClassName('no-Events')[0];

    if(e.target.classList.contains('day')){
        //Clear previous event Text
        clearEventText();

        if(eventData.events.length===0){
            noEvents.style.display='initial';
            noEvents.innerHTML = `There are no events on ${headerMonths.innerHTML} ${e.target.innerHTML} ${headerYears.innerHTML}`;
        } else {
            [...eventData['events']].forEach((event)=>{
                if(event['day']===e.target.innerHTML && event['month']===headerMonths.innerHTML && event['year']===headerYears.innerHTML){
    
                    //show event Text
                    showEventText(event['description']);
    
                }  else if(!checkEvents('year',headerYears.innerHTML) || !checkEvents('month', headerMonths.innerHTML) || !checkEvents('day', e.target.innerHTML))  {
                    clearEventText();
                    noEvents.style.display='initial';
                    noEvents.innerHTML = `There are no events on ${headerMonths.innerHTML} ${e.target.innerHTML} ${headerYears.innerHTML}`;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

//click on x to remove event
document.addEventListener('click', (x)=>{
    //day clicked on
    let day = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
    let noEvents = document.getElementsByClassName('no-Events')[0];

    if(x.target.classList.contains('remove')){
        let eventText = x.target.parentNode.textContent.slice(0,-1);

        for(var i = eventData.events.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if(eventData.events[i]['day']===day.innerHTML && eventData.events[i]['month']===headerMonths.innerHTML && eventData.events[i]['year']===headerYears.innerHTML && eventData.events[i]['description']===eventText){
                eventData.events.splice(i,1);
                //remove event clicked on from view
                x.target.parentNode.classList.add('swingHide');
                setInterval(()=>{
                    x.target.parentNode.outerHTML='';
                },500);
                //if no events on day selected show message
                if(!checkEvents('year',headerYears.innerHTML) || !checkEvents('month', headerMonths.innerHTML) || !checkEvents('day', day.innerHTML)){
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        noEvents.style.display='initial';
                    },600)
                    noEvents.innerHTML = `There are no events on ${headerMonths.innerHTML} ${day.innerHTML} ${headerYears.innerHTML}`;
                    day.classList.remove('active-event');
                }
                //if events on day selected show them
                if(checkEvents('year',headerYears.innerHTML) && checkEvents('month', headerMonths.innerHTML) & checkEvents('day', day.innerHTML)){
                    showEventText(eventData.events[i].description);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

 //adds json to eventData
function newEventJson(description, month, year, day){
    let event = {
        "description": description,
        "year": year,
        "month": month,
        "day": day
     };
     eventData.events.push(event);
 }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli');

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #649173,  #dbd5a4 );
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


/***** Container- calendar- Events ******/

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
}

.calendar {
    align-self:center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    min-height: 425px;
}

/***** Calender Header *****/

.date-header{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #649173,  #dbd5a4 );
    height:2em;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16),
     0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
     
}

.date-header .time-skip{
    height:100%;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 .2em 0 .2em;
}

.date-header .time-skip:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    cursor: pointer;
}

/***** Calendar Body *****/

.days-body thead .days-row th {
    padding: 1em;
    cursor: default;
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.days-body thead .days-row th:hover{
    color:yellow;
    transition: .5s;
}

.calendar-days td {
    padding: 1em;
    cursor: default;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    transition: all 600ms;
}

.calendar-days td:hover {
    background: #dd9756;
}

/******** Select Date *********/

.select-date {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-top: auto;
}

#month {
   margin-right: 40px;
}

#year {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
    height:100%;
    padding:0%;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    background: black;
}

#year::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
#year::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.select-date label {
    margin-left: 40px;
    align-self: center;
}

/****** Events ********/

.event-container{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #f2fcef, #eff7f1);
    border-left:none;
    display: flex;
    width:433px;
    height: 425px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y: auto
}

.events{
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; /*center children horizontally*/
    overflow-y: auto;
    justify-content: start;
    padding: 10px auto;
}

.events .event-message{
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #649173,  #dbd5a4 );
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 6px 10px #393a39;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.64,.34,1.76);
}

.event-desc {
    align-self: flex-start;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    order: -1;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}

.remove {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7.5px;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    line-height:12px;
    background-color: #69b6d5;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:14px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.hasEvent {
    background: #dd9756;
}

.active {
    background: blue;
}

.active-event {
    background: pink;
}

.error {
    color: red;
}

.show-event-form {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border: none;
    position:relative;
    font-weight:600;
    border-radius: 23px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    color:gray;
    box-shadow: 5px 8px 14px #393a39;
    background-color: #dbd5a4;
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  .show-event-form:hover{
      transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  .show-event-form::after{
      content:'';
      display:block;
      position: absolute;
      height:10px;
      width:10px;
      top:100%;
  }
/******** new Event Form **********/

.new-event-form{
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-align: center;
}

.new-event-form legend{
    font-size: 30px;
}

#new-event-desc{
    border:none;
    background-color:white;
    width: 40%;
    align-self: center;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    border-radius: 23px;
    padding:20px;
    outline:none;
}

#new-event-desc:focus{
    width:60%;
}

.submit-event{
    border: none;
    font-weight:600;
    border-radius: 23px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    color:gray;
    box-shadow: 5px 8px 14px #393a39;
    background-color: #dbd5a4;
    width:60%;
    align-self:center;
    padding:14px;
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.submit-event:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

/****animations*******/

.hidden {
    height: 0; opacity: 0; width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0ms 400ms, opacity 200ms 0ms, width 0ms 0ms;
}

.visible {
    height: 100%; opacity: 1; width: 100%;
    transition: height 200ms 0ms, opacity 600ms 200ms, width 0ms 0ms;
}

.swingHide {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.64,.34,1.76);
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.64,.34,1.76);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Calendar</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='resources/styles/main.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='calendar'>
                <div class='date-header'>
                    <span id='prev' class='time-skip'>prev</span>
                    <div class='year-month'>
                        <span class='month'></span>
                        <span class='year'></span>
                    </div>
                    <span id='next' class='time-skip'>next</span>
                </div>
                <table class='days-body'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr class='days-row'>
                            <th>Sun</th>
                            <th>Mon</th>
                            <th>Tue</th>
                            <th>Wed</th>
                            <th>Thu</th>
                            <th>Fri</th>
                            <th>Sat</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class='calendar-days'></tbody>
                </table>
                <form class='select-date'>
                    <label for='month'>Go To: </label>
                    <select name='month' id='month'>
                        <option value=0>Jan</option>
                        <option value=1>Feb</option>
                        <option value=2>Mar</option>
                        <option value=3>Apr</option>
                        <option value=4>May</option>
                        <option value=5>Jun</option>
                        <option value=6>Jul</option>
                        <option value=7>Aug</option>
                        <option value=8>Sep</option>
                        <option value=9>Oct</option>
                        <option value=10>Nov</option>
                        <option value=11>Dec</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='number' min='1' id='year'>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class='event-container'>
                <div class='events visible'>
                    <span class='no-Events event-message'>There are no events today</span>
                    <button class='show-event-form rotate'>Add new event</button>
                </div>
                <form class='new-event-form hidden'>
                    <legend>Submit New Event</legend>
                    <input id='new-event-desc' type='text' name='desc' placeholder='desc'>
                    <input type='submit' class='submit-event rotate' value='submit'>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='resources/js/calendar.js' async></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What code are you specifically referring to that you consider to be repeated?

Comment: I made the noEvents variable several times to set the display to hide or show it. I could have made a function for this, and there are a lot of if statements in my eventHandlers that could have been put into seperate function because I'm repeating a lot of the same things, especially if I want to add more features to this like editing events.

Comment: Yes, `let noEvents = document.getElementsByClassName('no-Events')[0]` appears to be able to be defined once. The `if..else` statements are unique within each function body, correct?

Comment: The if statements are unique but in some functions like the hideShowEventsDiv() I repeat a lot of adding and removing classes and this makes my code harder to read. I've seen a .toggle class in jquery to do the same thing but there is no equivalent in ECMAScript that I know of. Other functions like showEventText do several different things that I could have separated into several functions.

Comment: See [`toggle( String [, force] )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)